# remove substring followed by a comma in java

Tags: java, string

I want to remove numbers separated by a comma in a string:

```
String s= "1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 1000";
s= s.replace("1000","");
System.out.println(s);
```

The result is:

```
", 2000, 3000, 4000,"
```

I want to cut also leading and tailing commas, so the expected result is:

```
"2000, 3000, 4000"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: First replace `"1000, "` with `""` and then `", 1000"` with `""`.

Comment: Is there another way to delete something from a string?

Comment: I'd look whether trim() can accept different chars as just spaces ...

Comment: but I suppose if you have "x, 1000, y", you don't want to end up with "x, , y", do you ?

Comment: Tell me about your string format, do you have just one string that you have specified in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

```
String s = "1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 11000, 1000";
s = s.replaceAll("\b(1000, |, 1000)\b", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
2000, 3000, 4000, 11000
```

Or I would use a proper List

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(
                         1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 1000, -1000, 11000 ));
while(ints.remove((Integer) 1000));
System.out.println(ints);
```

prints

```
[2000, 3000, 4000, -1000, 11000]
```

If you really have to use String, you can do

```
String s = "1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 1000, -1000, 11000";
List<String> ints = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(", ")));
while (ints.remove("1000")) ;
System.out.println(ints);
```

prints

```
[2000, 3000, 4000, -1000, 11000]
```

Comment: I'd have gone for the list conversion in other languages as well. I suppose you have sometyhing like `String s = ints.join(", ")` in java too ...

Comment: s = s.replaceFirst("^1000(, )?", ""); returns "2000, 3000, 4000, 1000" not "2000, 3000, 4000"

Comment: @markus Ok, fixed,. I would still use a collection of numbers rather than mess about with Strings. The latest regex doesn't handle negative numbers :|

Comment: ok  s.replaceAll("\\b(1000(, )|(, )1000)?", ""); also does it. I need to remove it from a string, the original code can also contain characters thanks.

Comment: The `(, )` can be just `, `, The `?` at the end doesn't do anything.

Comment: I cannot compile the `List` example (`illegal initializer for List<Integer>`) and won't the `.remove(1000)` try to remove index 1000?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s= "1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 1000";
s= s.replace("1000","");
String[] spl=s.split(',');
String result="";
for(int i=0;i<spl.length;i++)
{ 
  if(spl[i].length()>1)//for space
   result+=spl[i]+",";      
}
result=result.substring(0,result.length()-2);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is related with `Java`, but if anyone want to achieve same in `Javascript` then its solution is

## Code

```
var s = "1000, 2000, 3000, 1000, 4000, 11000, 1000";
s = s.replace(/(1000, |, 1000)/g, "");
alert(s);
```

## Output

```
2000, 3000, 4000, 11000
```

## Live Demo